# Got 400 error while installing Angular CLI on windows 10 behind proxy server

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I just started to learn angular and need to install Angular CLI on my PC (Windows 10) behind a proxy server. My node version is **v12.13.1** and npm version is **6.12.1**.

I went to the Settings --> Network & Internet --> Proxy and copy the whole value in Script address field and update the config file with that value:

```
https-proxy=Script address value
proxy=Script address value
```

Now, when I run `npm install -g @angular/cli` I get this error below:

> npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli

and this is log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.1
3 info using node@v12.13.1
4 verbose npm-session 273f364019e6cde2
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 400 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli 643ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@latest 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 968ms
11 verbose stack Error: 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
11 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
12 verbose statusCode 400
13 verbose pkgid @angular/cli@latest
14 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
17 verbose node v12.13.1
18 verbose npm  v6.12.1
19 error code E400
20 error 400 Bad Request - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Could you please let me know what am I missing here and how I can resolve the issue.

Thanks for your help.

### UPDATE (Solution)

Thanks for your comments. I checked the URL and changed my proxy to localhost and it works. The config file looks as below:

```html
proxy=http://localhost:8888/proxy.pac
https-proxy=http://localhost:8888/proxy.pac
http-proxy=http://localhost:8888/proxy.pac
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782733/getting-error-400-bad-request-when-installing-angular-cli) might be similar to yours take a look at the answers and check if any if them provide an answer to your question

Comment: Try this: [#49782733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782733/getting-error-400-bad-request-when-installing-angular-cli) Asked 1 year, 8 months ago

Comment: Thanks @KevinHernandez

Comment: Thanks @LuanAlvesdaSilva

Comment: @mshojaei You dont have to edit your post with the answer you can answer your own question below and then accept it as the answer in a couple of days!

Answer (score 0):

I used localhost instead of our proxy URL and it resolved the issue. below is my config file:

```
proxy=http://localhost:8888/proxy.pac
https-proxy=http://localhost:8888/proxy.pac
http-proxy=http://localhost:8888/proxy.pac
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
```